# How to populate droplist field option using fastquery and option should be based on language-wise

Tags: wffm, multisite

How to populate droplist field option using fastquery and option should be based on language wise?

Comment: Reposting the exact same question that has previously been closed as off topic under reference to http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post - is not good form. Please expand your question in accordance with our guidelines, including context of your question, what you have tried and what results you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore Fast Query does not support language filtering.

> Fast query does not account for the context language (results include items with versions that match the query in any language)

Source: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. In that case, Can you please guide how to achieve my requirement